# React widget with routing inside single wordpress page

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router

I have a "normal" WP site, with pages, posts etc... On one of my pages Im using a custom template with React APP inside, which has its own routing. For example `domain.com/react-page`. When I change route in my React app - `domain.com/react-page/react-route` WP tries to find that page and of course it resolves to `404`, because it is a react route and not WP.

How to capture all routes only on this page for React routes?

Here's my standard *.htaccess*

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Do I need to create some condition for my React page `domain.com/react-page/`?

Comment: Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: Yes, inside my React widget.

Comment: Can you try to set `basename="/react-page"`?

Comment: That would affect the whole website, but I want other WP pages to resolve to their permalinks